# DataType equivalent in Protobuf

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I know that the data-types supported by protobuf-c are restricted to the ones mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) , but what can be a good protobuf-c equivalent to the following data types in C

time_t,
int8_t,
int16_t,
uint8_t,
uint16_t,
ushort

Answer (score 1):

For `time_t`, use `uint64_t`.

For all the others, use `sint32_t` (often negative), `int32_t` (rarely negative), or `uint32_t` (never negative). Protobuf uses a variable-width encoding for integers that avoids using more space on the wire than is really needed. For instance, numbers less than 128 will be encoded in 1 byte by `int32_t`.